# Should my answer to a bad question have been downvoted?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer, bad-questions

[A recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586766/plotting-latitude-longitude-on-map-in-r/49587100#49587100) I posted provides precisely what the OP was looking for and yet it has been downvoted, which I do not fully understand.

I reckon the question shows a clear lack of research and implementation effort and "SO is not a coding writing service" (to quote one of the comments). But at the same time, providing an answer was no trouble at all; quite the contrary, as I enjoy coding.

Now, abstracting from this particular case, should a good answer to a bad question be downvoted?

1. [This meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252656/punish-answerers-of-bad-questions) leads me to believe that most would agree bad-question-answerers should not be punished.
2. Neither [on this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254549/how-to-decide-which-questions-i-should-not-answer) nor [on this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267540/dont-answer-bad-questions) or [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions) was I able to discern a "downvote good answers" guideline. As a matter of fact, the accepted answer on the latter post advises not to.
3. Finally, [on another post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) the community seems to agree one should not advise on an off-topic question.

On balance, maybe I shouldn't have advised, but rather than downvoting a good answer, isn't the appropriate approach to simply downvote/flag the question and let the community/experienced users take care of it?

Comment: [Your link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586766/plotting-latitude-longitude-on-map-in-r/49587100#49587100) shows a not-so-good answer, one that is essentially a code-dump without explanation text. Please understand that an answer's explanation is much more important than the code, since questions and answers should be helpful to future visitors with similar problems and not just the original poster.  This is not a "please provide me with working code" site, but rather a "let's provide the world with helpful Q/A's for common coding problems".

Comment: And now you've improved it some, which is good. Still the question should be closed as a duplicate and eventually deleted since it will not add much to the knowledge base that is already on this site.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the feedback - was not aware of it. And yes I added more text to the code (basically what I my comments as plain text and a resource to learn more about it).

Comment: Note that I have notified the [SO Close Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) site that the question needs closing. It really is of very low quality and a duplicate, one that shows no evidence of research whatsoever, essentially little more than a "please write code for me" request. There are some questions that are of such low quality that they *shouldn't* be answered before improvement, and this is probably one of them.

Comment: I am not advocating for keeping bad questions, frankly I don't care about it. I just feel people downvote answers in order to have their way, i.e. avoiding bad questions. This is what I fail to understand.

Comment: Members of this site are free to down-vote as they see fit, and yes some *will* down-vote an answer to a question if the question's quality is horrifically low. Is this right and proper? In my view, probably not. Should it be "outlawed"? No, absolutely not, and for that matter, it can't be outlawed. So there you have it -- if you answer horrifically bad questions, you will be at risk for such down-votes, like it or not.

Comment: Maybe I did not express myself clearly. My aim is merely to understand the "guidelines" of SO. (And I did not complain about the votes or ask to forbid such behavior). At any rate, I will keep your words mind from now on when answering questions.

Comment: This has been debated back and forth for as long as I've been on this site, and I think that there are polarized opinions on this. I don't think that there are any set "guidelines" in that there is no prohibition from answering a bad question. But there are risks, as I've mentioned above.

Comment: There is also a consensus that answering and questions only encourages more bad questions. Why should OPs learn o postgood questions? Their bad questions get answered anyway. If they get banned, they start a new account and continue. By not answering bad questions you force the last OPs in doing some work before coming here.

Answer (score 7):

There are only 2 guidlines for downvoting answers:

1. "This answer is not useful" - You can see it when you hover over the downvote button and it's not much of a guidline. Everybody are free to decide what qualifies; if I think that answering bad questions is not useful and want to downvote that is my prerogative.
2. Don't vote based on who posted the answer, only based on content. - not really relevant to your question.